# ExtJS Gridpanel with textfield column

Tags: extjs

How to add a Textbox Column in a GridPanel. Editor feature of Gridpanel displays textbox only on doubleclick on the cell. But I want the textboxes in the column to be displayed by default.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite understand the need for such a thing. Textboxes are either used to enter or display data and both of these things can be done using the editor grid. There's even a `clicksToEdit` option to allow edit on 1 click of the column!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a config option or component for this. You can try to work around it by adding the textfield in the "renderer"

Answer (score -1):

You can define property like editor: textField in the column model of the grid that will display textbox in the column model.